# Format user input with thousands seperator

Tags: javascript, react-native, formatting

I have written a currency formatter that takes user inputs and displays it in currency format eg( user inputs 1000, it is supposed to show up as 1,000.00 This is my code below

```
const Currency = (props) => {
  const defaultOptions = {
    significantDigits: 2,
    thousandsSeparator: ",",
    symbol: props.symbol ? props.symbol : "NGN",
  };
  const amountValue = props.value ? props.value : 0.0;
  const formatCurrency = () => {
    let localAmount = amountValue;
    if (typeof localAmount !== "number") {
      localAmount = 0.0;
    }
    const currency = Math.floor(localAmount).toString();
    return `${defaultOptions.symbol} ${currency.replace(
      /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,
      `$1${defaultOptions.thousandsSeparator}`
    )}`;
  };
  return <Text {...props}>{formatCurrency()}</Text>;
};
```

However I want to modify it to not display the decimal part, for example when a user enters 12345678, I want to display it as 12,345,678 and not 12,345,678.00

When I try to modify it, the thousand separator no longer works as it should

Comment: In case anyone else finds it, my code snippet actually worked and the problem was in the component where I was using it, I just had to modify the precision from 2 to 0 and that fixed it.

<FormControl.Label>
  Amount
</FormControl.Label>
<CurrencyInput
  precision={2}
  minValue={0}
  delimiter={","}
  separator={"."}
  style={{ ...Shared.TextInput.roundedInput, fontSize: 18 }}
  placeholder={"Enter Amount"}
  onChangeValue={(t) => {
    setAmount(t);
  }}
  variant={"rounded"}
  value={amount}
  keyboardType={"numeric"}
/>

P.S: All of this is React-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did works as expected [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/format-thousands-without-zero-affix)

```js
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const getCurrency = (props) => {
  const defaultOptions = {
    significantDigits: 2,
    thousandsSeparator: ",",
    symbol: props.symbol ? props.symbol : "NGN",
  };
  const amountValue = props.value ? props.value : 0.0;
  const formatCurrency = () => {
    let localAmount = amountValue;
    if (typeof localAmount !== "number") {
      localAmount = 0.0;
    }
    const currency = Math.floor(localAmount).toString();
    return `${defaultOptions.symbol} ${currency.replace(
      /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,
      `$1${defaultOptions.thousandsSeparator}`
    )}`;
  };
  return <Text {...props}>{formatCurrency()}</Text>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    {getCurrency({value: 12345678})}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the browser do all the work for you with [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat). This example uses the `stripIfInteger` option to truncate the currency if the minor unit is all zeros.

> "stripIfInteger": remove the fraction digits if they are all zero. This is the same as auto if any of the fraction digits is non-zero.

```js
const number = 12345678;
const locale = 'en-NG';

const options = {
  style: "currency",
  currency: 'NGN',
  trailingZeroDisplay: 'stripIfInteger'
};

const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, options);
console.log(formatter.format(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {        
    minimumIntegerDigits: 3,
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
}).format(123456789)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).